# How to pass more than one value to a single column in where clause of sql select statement using python job

Tags: python

I want to select col1, col2. Col3 from sql table by passing col3 values in where clause using python script.
Scenario is I have the col3 values as a list which I want to pass to get the corresponding col1, col2 value from the table.

```py
List=[123,43,5678,345]
```

```
Tablename -test
Col1    col2    col3
XX       name    123
AW       sign     34
TR       pet      43
WF       address 5678
```

Result I want, I need to pass all the list values in single statement and to get result showing its col1 col2 value.

I tried this,

```sql
Select * from test where col3=?, (list,)
```

But it's not taking list of values passing to col3